# BBC Ghosts: Why can't Robin leave the grounds of Button House?

Tags: ghosts-bbc

In the BBC series "Ghosts", the ghosts that haunt Button House can't leave the grounds of the house, because they died in the house or within the grounds. But the house was built, and the grounds set up, centuries after Robin the caveman lived and died on that area of land. So why is he limited to the grounds like the other ghosts?

Comment: To quote Thomas: "Yes, it doesn't make sense, does it? ‍♂️"

Comment: Why are the pilots limited to the bounds of their aeroplane that only existed there for a moment? Why can the soldier only go so far down the lane he died on?

Comment: Well, the plague victims (and probably Mary) predate Button House and property lines. Their village was on the site and therefore their home anchor spot. I can only assume that Robin’s tribe also had a special claim and link to this area in the prehistoric once-upon-a-time.

Comment: For what it's worth, in my head, whatever supernatural power keeps them there can decide to draw the boundaries wherever it wants, and change them over time if it feels like it. Ghosts can move on from their existence, so it might even be trying to establish conditions where that's more likely to happen.